# Can i use header column search datatables laravel instead of footer column search

Tags: laravel, datatables

The following script shows the search boxes on table footer section

```
initComplete: function () {
    this.api().columns().every(function () {
        var column = this;
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
            .on('change', function () {
                column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
            });
    });
}
```

Can I display the search box in top of table after the columns names:

I tried to change the function column.footer to column.header ...
it not works.

I am using laravel datatables

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following, instead '#users' use your table id.

```
"initComplete": function () {
    var r = $('#users tfoot tr');

    $('#users thead').append(r);

    this.api().columns().every(function () {
        var column = this;
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                .on('change', function () {

       column.search($(this).val(), false, false,true).draw();
                });
    });

}
```